# Looking for a diagram to explain WSGI

Tags: python, diagram, wsgi

To help further my understanding of WSGI I'm looking for a diagram which explains the flow of an application, from webserver (eg. apache) through a number of middlewares to "code" (as in, the `print "hello world"` bit).

I've read various articles regarding WSGI from wsgi.org, but it's still not "clicking" for me and as for diagrams Google isn't bringing anything useful back except [this](http://uswaretech.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/django_request_response_lifecycle.png) for django which, while interesting, is expecting the user to understand how middleware links-up and such.

Since "a picture is worth a thousand words", are there any diagrams out there which get a bit lower/more simplistic than this?

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/?  Is that simplistic enough?  Have you looked at http://docs.python.org/library/wsgiref.html?  Is that simplistic enough?  Have you looked at http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/? Is that simplistic enough?

Comment: @S.Lott: Sorry, where did I say that I was looking for long descriptions of WSGI?

Comment: @Phillip Oldham: Are you saying that the sample applications in the WSGI descriptions aren't described well-enough?  Which of the three sources is closer to what you're looking for?  Why are you focused on a diagram when you have sample code?  What's wrong with the sample code?

Comment: @S.Lott: sometimes sample code isn't enough to illustrate the underlying concept. That's why whiteboards, UML, info-graphics etc. are so useful. A couple of boxes and arrows can often trump a well thought-out and written description.

Comment: @S.Lott Which part of *Looking for a diagram to explain WSGI* you don't understand?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: "simple diagram" and "explain WSGI" are both actually confusing.  Since the WSGI protocol is already simple, it doesn't make much sense to ask for a simple diagram.  So.  It would help to describe what parts of WSGI are confusing or complex-seeming or unclear.  Merely demanding "simple" isn't helpful.  Describing specific areas of confusing is helpful.  The words are vague.  I don't know the person asking.  I don't know what they know and what they don't know.  I hesitate to guess.  I feel that it's better to ask.  Perhaps I'm wrong in asking for clarification?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As I gained nothing by looking at Ian's fancy tubes I decided to draw a diagram myself. I hope it will help someone understand how WSGI flow works. As long as you have suggestions how to make it better I'm open to modify it. It was created with [LUCIDCHART](https://www.lucidchart.com/users/registerLevel/155237?tP=1&t10=A) webapp. The original diagram you can find [here](http://www.lucidchart.com/documents/view/4e8cd735-776c-4b7a-b8a0-780b0afc7621) and the high quality PNG is [here](http://www.lucidchart.com/publicSegments/view/4e9205ed-ad18-495e-bbb0-04c20a7f0d03/image.png).

[image: WSGI Flow]

Answer (score 9):

I like [the diagram](http://svn.colorstudy.com/home/ianb/wsgi-tutorial/diagram.png) from Ian Bicking's [WSGI - A Series of Tubes](http://svn.colorstudy.com/home/ianb/wsgi-tutorial/slides.odp).

Comment: Perfect! All it takes is some pointy arrows, some colored boxes, and "understanding" slots into place. Thanks!

Comment: And the crayon style is refreshing :)

Comment: HAH, that presentation is pretty good. I had no idea it existed. FWIW, the author of the presentation created Paste which I consider to one of the best resources for learning WSGI.

Comment: I gained literally nothing by looking at Ian's fancy tubes (diagram?) and decided to create my own which you can see in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303118/looking-for-a-diagram-to-explain-wsgi/7706396#7706396) to this question.

Comment: Could you provide the picture in the answer right here? 
It's unavailiable by the link provided by now.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if I can provide the answer you are looking for but the diagram you linked to shows more than just wsgi. The wsgi layer ends at the second line on the diagram. After that it's application specific.

WSGI is more an interface definition or contract that boils down to somehow you provide a function which takes a dictionary (environ) which represents the contents of the current request. and a function to call when you are ready to start the response(start_response).

The start_response method that you call needs a HTTP status code('200 OK') and a list of HTTP headers([('content-type', 'text/html')]).

```
def say_hello(envron={},start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('content-type', 'text/html')])
    return ["Hello from WSGI"]
```

Linking up your web server to your wsgi app is specific to your webserver I think and information on how the webserver arrives at the environ dictionary and a callback for your code to call is the webserver magic that you probably don't need to be concerned about. And as long as you obey the protocol, the webserver doesn't need to care how you arrived at your list of output that constitutes your response from your application.

The [Paste](http://pythonpaste.org/do-it-yourself-framework.html#what-is-wsgi) documentation helped me a LOT. You may find it useful. BTW, Paste is a bunch of useful things that help you utilize WSGI.And the docs are very good for understanding how to use WSGI and by extension Paste.

I know you asked for a diagram sorry. :(

Comment: The link to paste(WSGI) documentation was very helpful. Helped me understand WSGI. +1